# Are novelizations of films (or television) on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Quite simply asked, novelizations *are* literature, but they started as "screen" works. Should they be considered on-topic?

Comment: If *Harry Potter* is on-topic on [movies.se], I fail to see how it doesn't work the other way around for e.g. the *Interstellar* novelization. It has to be clear about which medium the question is really asked, though.

Comment: Is 2001 an example for your question ;)

Comment: @Montag451 Not really, it was a book first, wasn't it?

Comment: @ChristianRau No, it wasn't. It's rather a very complicated story. http://www.openculture.com/2015/07/difference-between-stanley-kubricks-arthur-c-clarkes-2001-a-space-odyssey.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

As you say, they're written works. It doesn't really matter where they started off; every idea came from *somewhere*, after all. Being written works makes them on-topic (in just the same way that cinematisations of novels are on-topic at our sister site [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com)). Usual caveats apply: if you want to ask a question that's actually about a film, better to ask it somewhere films are actually on-topic rather than posting it here in the guise of a question about a novelisation.

It should be noted that *quality* of a written work isn't a criterion for its on-topic-ness ...

Comment: Hmm... now what about movie scripts?

Comment: @Skooba - same, they are works of writing.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes.

They may be related to non-book works, but they are works of literature nonetheless.

They are written by writers and are textual and tell a story.

Moreover, they are frequently different from the movies, and often are more in-depth, covering internal thoughts and motivations in great detail.

(and sometimes, are better than the movie in some ways - my personal subjective example is Revenge of the Sith novelization, in which Anakin's character arc makes about 100x more sense than in the film).