# Are questions on online literature and e-books on-topic? if yes, then please make tags for them

Tags: discussion, scope, tags

I asked [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/250/195) question on Literature SE, related to online published e-book. But I had no clue of what tag to attach. There are no generic tags like: "E-book","Online-Literature" etc.

Since there are no tags, I think, Literature SE might not be considering questions related to e-books and online literature on topic. Is it so? If not, then please formulate tags for that.

Comment: Please do NOT create (or at least use) meta tags like e-book or online-literature for the purpose of tagging questions about individual works that happen to be e-books or online. Those tags should **only** be used (if at all) for questions dealing with generic issues involving e-books as a thing, or online literature as a phenomenon.

Comment: @DVK Good catch. The acid test I use to determine if something is likely a meta tag is to ask yourself: "Is this question about the *subject* of [ebooks]?" (for example) In this case, **the answer is almost certainly *no.*** (i.e. so it's a meta tag to be avoided) [The death of meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, these should be on-topic.

As I've already said on a few other [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) meta questions, why not? They're written works, and they can be just as interesting and worthy of analysis as paper books. In fact, many books are published in both forms: as a paper book *and* an e-book. It would be silly to allow questions about one but not the other.

Note [again](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/17) that *quality* of a written work isn't a criterion for its on-topic-ness (and would be hard to determine objectively anyway).

### Create the tags yourself!

It's private beta, so [anyone can create tags](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). A tag will exist on the site if and only if there is a question with that tag. At this stage, **if you want a new tag, just create it yourself by asking a question with it**. Don't worry too much about making a mistake or creating a 'wrong' tag; someone else can always edit your question if you do.

However, as mentioned in comments on the question, the tags you should be using for such questions are **tags for the individual works, *not* an [online-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-literature) or [ebooks](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebooks) tag**. The latter would probably count as [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/): they don't describe what the question is *about*, but just function as category tags. See also [this answer](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/296/17) on broad tags from Robert Cartaino.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course. I think the limiter here is "still words vs. moving pictures." So a graphic novel (which uses illustrations to tell a story) is fine, a graphic novel sold as an e-book is fine, but movies and TV are not.